# Small currency converter

Tags: ruby, converters, currency

I started making a currency converter. This is what the code looks like:

```
print"What currency would you like to convert from?(british,yen):"
currency_in = gets.to_s
print"What currency would you like to convert to?(british,yen):"
currency_out = gets.to_s
print"How much would you like to convert?:"
to_c = gets.to_f
if (currency_in == "british") && (currency_out == "yen")
  puts to_c * 181.69 + "Y"
elsif (currency_in == "yen") && (currency_out == "british")
  puts to_c * 0.01 
else
  puts"no such currency"
end
```

But it does not work as I expect. When I type `british` then `yen`, or other way around, the program keeps going to `"no such currency"`.

Answer (score 2):

[`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) will include a newline character (`"\n"`) at the end of the String. You can remove it using [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
currency_in = gets.chomp
print "What currency would you like to convert to?(british,yen):"
currency_out = gets.chomp

# ...
```